# OpenStack Kilo DevStack install fails noVNC issue

Tags: git, openstack, devstack, novnc

Trying to install devstack (Kilo) on a VM (ubuntu 64 bit 14.04.3 desktop) running on a local machine.

Its throwing a git error in the middle of installation:

> error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200 | 0 bytes/s

and

> [ERROR] /home/[username]/devstack/functions-common:605 git call failed:
>   [git clone https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC.git /opt/stack/noVNC]

for troubleshoot I did this:

> git config --global http.postBuffer 2000M
>   and 
>   git config pack.windowMemory 1500M

but it didn't worked!

I tried installation a bunch of time but its time consuming and frustrating! ..well any suggestions?

See following for more error details..

```
+ NOVNC_FROM_PACKAGE=False
+ '[' False = True ']'
+ NOVNC_WEB_DIR=/opt/stack/noVNC
+ git_clone https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC.git /opt/stack/noVNC master
+ local git_remote=https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC.git
+ local git_dest=/opt/stack/noVNC
+ local git_ref=master
+ local orig_dir
++ pwd
+ orig_dir=/home/[username]/devstack
+ local git_clone_flags=
++ trueorfalse False RECLONE
++ local xtrace
+++ set +o
+++ grep xtrace
++ xtrace='set -o xtrace'
++ set +o xtrace
+ RECLONE=False
+ [[ 0 -gt 0 ]]
+ [[ False = \T\r\u\e ]]
+ echo master
+ egrep -q '^refs'
+ [[ ! -d /opt/stack/noVNC ]]
+ [[ False = \T\r\u\e ]]
+ git_timed clone https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC.git /opt/stack/noVNC
+ local count=0
+ local timeout=0
+ [[ -n 0 ]]
+ timeout=0
+ timeout -s SIGINT 0 git clone https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC.git /opt/stack/noVNC
Cloning into '/opt/stack/noVNC'...
remote: Counting objects: 4946, done.
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200 | 0 bytes/s      
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
+ [[ 128 -ne 124 ]]
+ die 605 'git call failed: [git clone' https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC.git '/opt/stack/noVNC]'
+ local exitcode=0
+ set +o xtrace
[Call Trace]
./stack.sh:813:stack_install_service
/home/[username]/devstack/lib/stack:31:install_nova
/home/[username]/devstack/lib/nova:748:git_clone
/home/[username]/devstack/functions-common:539:git_timed
/home/[username]/devstack/functions-common:605:die
[ERROR] /home/[username]/devstack/functions-common:605 git call failed: [git clone https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC.git /opt/stack/noVNC]
Error on exit
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2015-10-29-012838.txt for details
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a folder "/opt/stack/noVNC" and manually downloaded the noVNC files from git in it.. (https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC)

ran the ./devstack again and devstack installation/setup went through..

Thanks